# java 8 adjustable time scheduler

Tags: java

I need to implement the following functionality:
I have something like a messenger. So, user sends messages, and system should wait 3 sec after last message. So, for example user sends 'Hello!',and system should start countdown, and if 2 seconds passed and user sends 'hey!', it should start counting down again. If 3 secs has passed, special action should fire. Are there any special classes and technologies for this in java and java frameworks?

**UPDATE:**

Basically I need something ready to implement a time barrier with ability to change waiting time. So, I need to wait 3 secs after LAST message came. So, when API gets message 'Hello', it should start waiting for 3 secs before perform some action. If 2 secs passed and API gets next message 'Hey', it should init it's time counter and start counting down seconds again. So, totally 5 secs are passed. And If there's no message to API for 3 secs after last message, action should run.

If I do Thread.sleep or future.get I specify fixed number of secs to delay, but I want to have ability to change this number online and system should take it. For example:

```
int counter=5;//any shared seconds quantity holder

while(true){
  counter--;
  Thread.sleep(1000);
}

....

setCounter(5);//I call somewhere, and loop will be looping again.
```

But I am looking for something stable and tested, not to invent a bicycle.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't get your question, are you asking about automated messaging system?

Comment: could you add some details to make it more specific? what kind of messenger? how do they communicate?

Comment: Thread.sleep??? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html

Comment: You need to schedule an operation. See `ScheduledExecutorService` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

Comment: well if you want a fancy solution, you could try RxJava, create an Observable with a timeout, but you could also try just sleep in a loop...